# Get Error number in WebException Error

Tags: c#, webexception

How To Get Error number in WebException Error?

```
try
{
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("site");
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     int i = stream.ReadByte();
}
catch (WebException e)
{
     //How To Get Error number in WebException Error?
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll want to run a test to make sure that it was a `ProtocolError`:

```
if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
}
```

Comment: How get **HTTP Substatus** value ? For example, _404.13 Content Length Too Large_ Reference: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Answer (score 7):

For Get Error Number:

```
catch(System.Net.WebException e)
{
    int errorNumber = (int)e.Status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse the message, but there isn't always an error number. A timeout for example doesn't result in an HTTP error code.